# Reinstalling packages from a list generated by command: ado dir

Tags: installation, stata, restore

I am recovering Stata following a Windows upgrade. I have a list of my packages generated from `ado dir` in the following format:

[1] package mdesc from http://fmwww.bc.edu/RePEc/bocode/m
      'MDESC': module to tabulate prevalence of missing values

[2] package univar from http://fmwww.bc.edu/RePEc/bocode/u
      'UNIVAR': module to generate univariate summary with box-and-whiskers plot

[3] package tabmiss from http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/ado/analysis
      tabmiss. Shows tabulation of number of missing and non-missing values

I have many packages and would like to reinstall them without having to designate each directory/url via `net cd`. While using `net cd` along with `net install` or `ssc install` along with package names in a loop is trivial (as below), it would seem that an automated method for this task might be available.

```
net cd http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/ado/analysis
    local ucla tabmiss csgof powerlog ldfbeta 
        foreach x of local ucla {
            net install `x'
        }
```

Comment: I see no reason why a reinstalled Stata should know in any sense what user-written packages you installed earlier, any more than Stata on one machine would know what is installed on another. More crucially, why would a Windows upgrade affect your Stata installation at all?

Comment: My machine was reimaged following ingestion of a root directory virus. An astute member of our IT team obtained the 'ado dir' result prior to wiping the machine and upgrading to Windows 10. STATA was reinstalled from a disc. I'm not suggesting STATA should have a memory of packages, but wanted to understand if there is a method for reinstalling given the list provided by 'ado dir.'

Comment: So the machine was wiped. I agree with @ander2ed's answer. Note that the spelling is Stata, not STATA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no built-in or automated method of tracking and managing your installed packages outside of what is available through `ado` or `net`.

I would also tend to agree with @Nick Cox that this task seems strange and I can't imagine how a new Stata install or reinstall could know what was installed previously, but I find the question interesting for other reasons.

The main reason being for users who have Stata installed on multiple machines who need the same packages on both machines. I faced a similar issue when I purchased a new computer and installed Stata but wanted all of the packages I use to be available as well. Outside of moving the ado directory or selected contents I'm not aware of any quick solution.

Here it would be possible to use the output of `ado dir` on one machine to determine what you need to install on a second machine with a new Stata install.

The method you propose using a `foreach` loop could save you time from having to type in or copy/paste a lot of packages and URLs. At the same time however, this is only beneficial if you have many packages from only a few repositories because you will need to `net cd` to the URL each time as you show in your example.

An alternative solution is the programmatic solution. As you know, `ado dir` will list each installed package, the URL and a short description of the package. Using this, a log file, and the built in I/O functionality, a short program could be written to automate the process and dynamically build a do file that contains the commands to install the already installed packages.

The code below generates a do file containing commands (in this case, `net describe package, from(url)`) for each package I have installed on my computer.

```
clear *

tempfile log1
log using "`log1'", text name(mylog)
ado dir
log close mylog

tempname logfile
file open `logfile' using "`log1'", read
file read `logfile' line

file open dfh using "path/to/your/dofile.do", write replace

local pckage "package"

while r(eof) == 0 {
    if `: list pckage in line' {

        local packageName : word 3 of `line'
        local dirName : word 5 of `line'
        di "`packageName' `dirName'"

        file write dfh "net describe `packageName', from(`dirName')"
        file write dfh _newline

    }
    file read `logfile' line
}

file close `logfile'
file close dfh
```

In the above code, I create a temp file to write a .txt log file to and store the contents of `ado dir` in that file.

Then, I open the log file using `file open` and read it line by line in the `while` loop.

Above the loop, I'm creating a do file at `/path/to/your/dofile.do` to hold the output of the loop - the dynamically created commands relating to the installed packages on my machine.

The loop will iterate so long as `r(eof)` = 0, where `r(eof)` is an end of file marker. I use an `if` statement to sort out lines of the log file which contain the word package, as I'm only interested in those lines with the package name and URL in them.

Inside of the `if` block, I parse the local macro `line` to pull the package name and the URL/directory name.

*this is important: this section of code assumes that the 3rd and 5th words in the macro will always be the package name and URL respectively - Confirm this from the output of* `ado dir` *before executing.*

You will also need to change the command that is being written to the file handle dfh inside of the loop to what you want (`net install`, etc) when you are ready to execute.

For more help on using `file`, `local`s,  and `tempfile`s execute any of the following in Stata:

```
help file          
help extended_fcn 
help macrolists
```

There may be nicer ways to parse the contents of `ado dir` but this has worked for me. And of course I'd always advise that you take the time to understand what the code is doing so that you can make any necessary tweaks to fit your particular situation.